# nosetest is failing, but external use of code passes

Tags: python, debugging, travis-ci, nosetests

This problem has been bugging me for weeks now. I'm working on this [Hacker News API](https://github.com/karan/HackerNewsAPI) that works just fine. All tests pass locally:

```
(HackerNewsAPI)karan:HackerNewsAPI$ nosetests -v 
Checks if the pagination works for the front page. ... ok
Checks if the pagination works for the newest page. ... ok
Checks if the pagination works for the best page. ... ok
Checks if the dict returned by scraping the best page of HN is 30. ... ok
Checks if the dict returned by scraping the front page of HN is 30. ... ok
Checks if the dict returned by scraping the newest page of HN is 30. ... ok
Checks data type of each field of each story from best page ... ok
Checks data type of each field of each story from newest page ... ok
Checks data type of each field of each story from front page. ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 16.695s

OK
```

However, on Travis, one test fails - https://travis-ci.org/karan/HackerNewsAPI/jobs/15799138#L361

```
======================================================================
FAIL: Checks if the pagination works for the best page.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/travis/build/karan/HackerNewsAPI/tests/test_pagination.py", line 25, in test_pagination_best_for_2_pages
    assert len(stories) == 2 * 30
AssertionError: 
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): news.ycombinator.com
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: DEBUG: "GET /best HTTP/1.1" 200 None
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): news.ycombinator.com
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: DEBUG: "GET /x?fnid=rCw2Votbz10Qkphm6oqLL8 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
```

I have tried everything I can, looked everywhere, but can't find a solution. It fails on both py2 and py3. Just this specific test, not any other. And it does not fail on a local system.

What is wrong here?

Main code file: https://github.com/karan/HackerNewsAPI/blob/master/hn/hn.py
`.travis.yml` file: https://github.com/karan/HackerNewsAPI/blob/master/.travis.yml

**Addemdum**:

For the past hour or so, the specific test was failing locally too. So I started debugging it. The problem is, that in the test `test_pagination_best_for_2_pages`, `stories = hn.get_stories(story_type='best', page_limit=2)` should result in `len(stories) == 60` (30 stories on each page). But for some reason, it's only getting the first page (hence, 30 stories).

However, if I write a short program:

```
from hn import HN

hn = HN()
print len(hn.get_stories(story_type='best', page_limit=2))
```

This prints `60`. What is going on here?

Comment: Not really sure, but if you Google around you can find VM images for Travis's worker machines, as well as instructions for reconstructing them. You might want to give that a try and see if you can reproduce the problem by running the tests locally.  It's a start anyways.